# Размер массива структур

Tags: c

Вот такой код в CodeBlock работает без ошибок

```
typedef struct exmpl{
   int index; 
   char name[50];   
   int count; 
   } result;
        
   int size;
   scanf("%d", &size);
    
   result data[size];
```

Но в Visual Studio выдает ошибки

> error C2057: expected constant expression
>
> error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
>
> error C2133: 'data' : unknown size

Как я понимаю проблема не в IDE а в стандартах С или компиляторах ?

Comment: result *data = (result *)malloc(sizeof(result)*size);

Comment: @Sergey, динамически выделять память это конечно круто, но мне бы понять почему так можно делать.

Comment: Проблема, конечно же, не в IDE, а в компиляторах. Поэтому в вопросе надо уточнить, какой компилятор используется в CodeBlocks и какая версия Visual Studio.

Comment: @zed , CodeBlocks - GNU GCC Compile  r ---- follow C++11 language standart
---------------------------     
Visual Studio - 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Где именно вы объявляете ваш массив?

Если ваш массив объявлен локально, то вы пытаетесь использовать Variable Length Arrays (VLA) - свойство языка С начиная с версии С99. Компилятор MSVC не поддерживает VLA, даже несмотря на то, что в современном MSVC поддержка С99 реализована [почти] полностью. Стандарт С11 сделал VLA опциональным свойством языка, так что возможно мы никогда и не увидим их поддержки в MSVC.

В нелокальных же областях VLA объявляться не может.

Answer (score 2):

Нету в стандарте C массивов с динамическим выделением. Это была одноразовая слабость, реверанс в сторону фортранщиков, которую поддержали в GCC, который и применятся в CBlocks (дрянная кстати IDE, имеет самый дубовый конфигуратор проектов в этой части вселенной).

Так вот, хотите динамику - либо malloc/realloc/free, либо C++ и STL.

Comment: Variable Length Arrays являются стандарной фичей языка С начиная с С99. Какой GCC? Другое дело, что С11 сделал VLA опциональной фичей, но именно это было реверансом в сторону эмбедщиков. Де-факто VLA должны поддерживаться "полноценными" версиями компиляторов С.

Comment: @AnT я и говорю - минутная слабость в C99, которую потом выкинули из стандарта. И GCC тут как раз при том, что он эту опцию у себя реализует.

Comment: Так чья слабость: C99 или GCC? И нет, никто и никогда ее из стандарта не выкидывал. Как я сказал выше, цель опциональности VLA - дать больше свободы freestanding implementations (эмбедщики и прочие пользователи "урезанного" С). Для полноценных hosted implementations поддержка VLA де-факто обязательна.

Comment: @AnT комитета по стандартам, которые сначала фичу вкрутили (С99), а потом выкрутили (С11). Троллинг закончен, до свидания.